# Python package requires different module import paths when run locally Vs when installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-packaging

I have a python package that I wish to make installable, but when running locally to test Vs running after installed with `pip`, paths to imported modules in the package differ, so I can't use the package in both cases.

Long question short... how can I make my package work both locally without needing it installed with `pip`, and when installed with `pip`.

---

## Full Explaination

Here is my directory structure.

```bash
example_project
│   pyproject.toml
│   setyp.py
│   
└── src/pkg
    │   __main__.py
    │   assets.py
```

When using the first example (see code below), the package can be run locally and it works as expected.

```bash
user@computer:~/tools$ python example_project/src/pkg User
Hello, User.
```

However, after installing the package with `pip` and running, it fails to work.

```bash
user@computer:~/tools$ pip install example_project/
...
Successfully installed example-1.0.2
user@computer:~/tools$ example User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/example", line 5, in <module>
    from example.__main__ import entry_point
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/example/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from assets import say_hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'assets'
```

To seemingly fix everything, the import paths can be updated as shown in the second example (see code below), and now it appears as though the package works when run locally and when installed with `pip` and run. But that's not quite the whole story.

```bash
user@computer:~/tools$ python example_project/src/example User
Hello, User.
user@computer:~/tools$ example User
Hello, User.
```

The trouble is, if the package is uninstalled, it wont work locally. This makes sense, because `example` wouldn't be in the Python path. But how can I make this package work both locally without being installed, and when installed with `pip`?

```bash
user@computer:~/tools$ pip uninstall example
Found existing installation: example 1.0.2
Uninstalling example-1.0.2:
  ...
  Successfully uninstalled example-1.0.2
user@computer:~/tools$ python example_project/src/example User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/tools/example_project/src/example/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from example.assets import say_hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

---

#### First Example

```bash
mkdir -p example_project/src/example

cat <<EOF > example_project/setup.py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='example',
    version='1.0.2',
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['example = example.__main__:entry_point']},
)
EOF

cat <<EOF > example_project/pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
EOF

cat <<EOF > example_project/src/example/__main__.py
from assets import say_hello
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example')
parser.add_argument('name')
def entry_point() -> None:
    args = parser.parse_args()
    say_hello(args.name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    entry_point()
EOF

cat <<EOF > example_project/src/example/assets.py
def say_hello(name: str) -> None:
    print(f'Hello, {name}.')
EOF
```

#### Second Example

***Note:** Requires that all command from the first example (above) have been run.*

```bash
cat <<EOF > example_project/src/example/__main__.py
from example.assets import say_hello
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example')
parser.add_argument('name')
def entry_point() -> None:
    args = parser.parse_args()
    say_hello(args.name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    entry_point()
EOF
```

Comment: Use absolute imports. `import assets` can not work because `assets` is not a top-level import package/module.

Comment: @sinoroc, thanks for the reply, but unless I'm missing something, I have tried that and explained the results in my question. Because of how the package will be created and added to `site-packages`, I don't believe I can go any further than `example.assets`. where `example` is the package name and `assets` is the module I wish to import within the package.

Comment: Does this help? https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html -- `python -m example` should be enough since `example` is a top-level import package that contains a `__main__` module.

Comment: @sinoroc, that's exactly my issue. Using `example.assests` works for an installed package, but when testing locally without having the package installed that will fail.

Comment: Yes, things have to be installed. For local developement you can install as editable. With `python -m pip install --editable .` for example.